# Is there a way to get https requests to work when calling from a localhost for testing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I'm getting the errors when testing my application locally since I switched to https:

> Warning: Domain www.example.com does not specify a meta-policy.
>
> Applying default meta-policy 'master-only'.  This configuration is
>   deprecated.   See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix
>   this problem.
>
> Error: Request for resource at
>   https://www.example.com/?json=user/get_logged_in_user  by requestor
>   from http://localhost:8888/Test-debug/Test.swf is denied due  to lack
>   of policy file permissions.

I tried changing my localhost to `https` but got the following error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8888. SSL received
>   a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code:
>   SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
>   Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

From what I've read I can upload and add a policy file and changing secure to true but I don't want to allow calls from anywhere. Once the swf is on my server everything works fine.

Is there a way to get this to work locally for testing?     Is there something that I can enable while testing like:

```
Security.allowDomain("localhost");
```

Or do I have to upload a cross domain policy and then delete that policy when I'm done testing?

Since my local site is running locally in the browser shouldn't it be able to make a connection to a https connection?

Answer (score 1):

Using of https (btw it does not configured properly according to message you posted (did you use FireFox to test?)) will not help. The problem is that `www.example.com` does not have `crossdomain.xml` policy file, so flash player does not allow to access that domain from your `localhots` which is also a domain.

If you have an access to `www.example.com` add policy file here with wildcard access, if not - test via http is possible only with mocking response with some http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to testing using `file://` (no server) and it works making `https` calls.